# Cannot install symfony project using composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to install symfony using composer. I am using the following command

```
sudo composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /var/www/html/infinite-jest
```

But I am getting the following errors

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - sensio/distribution-bundle v3.0.12 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.0].
    - sensio/distribution-bundle v3.0.13 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.0].
    - sensio/distribution-bundle v3.0.14 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.0].
    - sensio/distribution-bundle v3.0.15 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.0].
    - sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for sensio/distribution-bundle ~3.0.12 -> satisfiable by sensio/distribution-bundle[v3.0.12, v3.0.13, v3.0.14, v3.0.15].
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Are you running on linux or mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you don't have curl or php curl extension installed in your system.
And it is now recommended to use the new [installer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) for symfony

Comment: Not just recommended, it is required.

Comment: from the doc : "Using the Symfony Installer is the only recommended way to create new Symfony applications". But not the only one:  in some cases like if you have only pHP 5.3 or want to use a legacy symfony version (1.x) you still have to go through composer

Comment: you've misinterpreted my comment. **curl** is not just recommended, it is required to use the installer.

Comment: I have successfully installed the symfony project. thanks for ur help :D

Comment: I think it's also what i wrote in my answer basically ??  Glad you made it

Comment: So could you please validate my answer ?